# Multiple css files with same filename

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to make [this](http://etimbo.github.com/jquery-print-preview-plugin/example/index.html) work with my MVC3 application. It looks like the javascript source is working fine. It appends the whole page(including head and body) to the bottom of the original and tries to use the css file. First time this  file is declared at the top of the page with attribute (media='print'). And it doesn't apply any changes on the page. The second time plugin declares it below, with attribute (media='all') and from this moment it should apply changes, show print preview and show buttons. But nothing happens, until I change manually attribute 'media' from 'print' to 'all' at the top of the page. Looks like first declaration is blocking second one. I can't use this css file all the time, because i need to hide some elements in print mode.
 Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add @media rule in css.

@media rule lets you group CSS rules by media type in one css file:

```
body {
color:#444;
background-color:#fff;
}
@media screen, projection {
body { background-image:url(background.png); }
}
@media print {
body { color:#000; }
}
@media handheld {
body { color:#0f6517; }
}
```

Comment: No use. Plugin is creating print preview over the page. I made sections "@media" in main css file. On button click made event which changes "media" attribute and it should hide login inputs to not display them on paper preview. But those inputs are hiding from main page also. I need to make those css rules to work with 'print' parameter from first <html> to </html> and with 'all' parameter from second <html> to </html>. Problem is 'print' parameter is working on both.